# AJAX and setInterval slows down the script

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, setinterval

i'm working on a script which reads things from a database, instantly.

I connect using AJAX and reload the function with an interval.
Actually i'm using multible setInterval() to get my information.

I know that that slows down the page and it does because it seems to be impossible to use it on mobile devices because it laggs to much.

But how can i do that?
Do you have any suggestions

Thanks.

Comment: Please, post some code.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using AJAX with intervals.

There are various methods for obtaining data from the server.
Your scenario suggests you are trying to get new data from the server. There are several ways to do that and it has been discussed here on SO and in other places thoroughly.

The main methods are server push (mainly via web-sockets) and fallback methods like long polling and normal polling.

You can use an asynchronous framework that has fallback to support older browsers.

To your specific question, if you insist on using polling (which is the repeated request of data at an interval), it is advised to set a timeout when the response arrives and not use an interval. This way, even if communication lags, you won't get out of sync and won't have simultaneous requests.

Comment: I now solved the problem using AJAX with JSON. That may not be perfect, but its only one interval left. I can reload the interval more often without lags :)